# How to Override CreateModelMixin corrctly

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I want to override CreateModelMixin with my own class which derived from ModelViewSet
this is the class i want to override
class CreateModelMixin:

```
    """
    Create a model instance.
    """
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

    def get_success_headers(self, data):
        try:
            return {'Location': str(data[api_settings.URL_FIELD_NAME])}
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            return {}
```

in the first instinct, I want to override only the create function with a different serializer
but would it be more correct to override `perform_create`?
if someone can guide me how it is the most correct way to override that will be much of help
thank you

Comment: Could you include the desired behavior or the problem you are trying to solve, so we can help.  You said something about a new serializer, so that means you'd need to override `create()` in your example.  However, there is also `get_serializer_class` and other hooks, so there may be a better way.  You can just create a new class, no need to inherit anything, if you are writing a new `create`.  Its the method name that matters for the routers/dispatch logic.

Comment: I have a message model and I want to do different things based on the URL is given
and I want to do it with modelviewset
and for most of the mixin functions I use the class serializer I defined but for the create I'm using a different serializer and I don't know which function is better to override

Comment: You can override `get_serializer_class` and check if `self.action == 'create'` and then return a different serializer for that specific call.